# getNamesByLocationAndYears from wikipedia

Tags: javascript, wikipedia

function getNamesByLocationAndYears(location, from, to)

execute "What links here" = locationk

```
get list of items
loop for every item from the list
{*      if item.MainType = "person" then
    {*
        with categories do
        {*
            if (births>from and births<to) or (deaths>from and deaths<to) then  
                              show-PersonName,births,deaths

        *} 

    *}
*}
```

*}

Hi, I have one question. I would like to execute one simple query to wikipedia. It is really simple, I am not a web 
programmer and I do not need anything else. Please, do somebody know any web page, where I can directly interactively
execute some JAVA query which gets me what I want by these request and mainly if it is no problem to someboby to write
this code? It is first time when I am asking to somebody else to write code for me. I have no time to learn new 
technologies outside my job. 10 lines in new technology takes me 20 hours of learning this technology and also wiki
apis and wiki manners.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Taylor, I have no time to read this, I thang, that internet is free instrument. Bergi, I do not know, how I wrote ... know any web page, where I can directly interactively execute some query? Not important if it is JAVA or not. It must be quick and simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the API, so I can't do it for you, but you can try queries here

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox

and here's some bedtime reading for you

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API

The sandbox isn't Java, but is URL based.  I'd give it a try for you but the code you sent doesn't help, and I don't know the API to have the foggiest idea how to do what you want, nor do I understand the context of all of this.

Good luck though!